# Cell Background in html

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to provide backgroud color to table cell based on the value this is what so far i have done:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .Scheduled {
        background-color: lime;
    }
     .Completed {
        background-color: lawngreen;
    }

    .Completed with error {
        background-color:red ;
    }

    .Pending {
        background-color: #ffbf00  ;
    }

   
</style>
```

```html
 <td class="@item.Status" >
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                        </td>
```

i want Complete with error cell to be in Red how can i do it? what i am doing wrong?

[image]

expected output:

[image]

Comment: can u provide your html and css plz so we can debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces in `.Completed with error` make it an invalid css class name.

If the class name was changed to `.Completed-with-error`, then it would become valid.

Let's fix this:

```
 <td class="@item.Status.Trim().Replace(' ', '-')" >
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
 </td>
```

Now change your CSS as well:

```
<style type="text/css">
.Scheduled {
    background-color: lime;
}

.Completed {
    background-color: lawngreen;
}

.Completed-with-error {
    background-color:red ;
}

.Pending {
    background-color: #ffbf00  ;
}
</style>
```

Voila!

---

**Updated:**
Add `.Trim()`, to clean up any trailing spaces.

Comment: I tried your solution but now cell's color of both "Completed" and "Completed with Error" is not working and turned to white instead. Please advise thanks

Comment: @RahDeshpande Can you inspect the element in the browser and see what the class names are? It's possible that there is a trailing space (which would be replaced with a dash)

Comment: It worked thanks. before .Trim() it was generation trailing dash

Answer (score 1):

So the first thing that I see is `.Completed with error` which is not a valid css class. You can't have spaces in a css class.

You'll need to amend the code so the class is `.Completed-with-error`. Both on the HTML and in the styles.

Comment: i changed css to .Completed-with-error but i cannot change the source from where the text is coming. what should i  change can you describe in breaf?

Answer (score 0):

you may find this useful, notice i dont have border outside table

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
td{
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
.pink{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="red">fjdfk fdfdf</td>
    <td class="green">fjdfk fdfdf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="blue">fjdfk fdfdf</td>
    <td class="pink">fjdfk fdfdf</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="red">fjdfk fdfdf</td>
    <td class="green">fjdfk fdfdf</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```